# Android compress audio file before upload

Tags: android

The application has a function for uploading audio files to the server. How i can compress an audio file? I did not find anything suitable on the github. Python server android client

Comment: Compress it to a zip file. But audio is not much compressable i think. Or you must have wav. And there are so many audio file formats and you are telling nothing.

Comment: With zipping you will not loose quality. And you shure should tell which format(s) you wanna upload. Or start telling what you have in mind concerning compression.

Comment: @blackapps mp3 format

Comment: And you wanna compress it to...? Or what should happen exactly?